# adding a subview in a method other than viewDidLoad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm adding a subview in a method other than `viewDidLoad()` and the subview is not displayed.
my code is here below:

```
 -(void) displayBanner
{ 

    SharedApp *instance=[SharedApp sharedInstance];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(targetMethod:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

 numTimerTicks = 0;

   roundedButtonType = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect]retain]; //Creates a UIButton
   roundedButtonType.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 360.0f, 320.0f, 60.0f); //sets the coordinates and dimensions of UIButton
   roundedButtonType.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; //sets the background color
   roundedButtonType.tag = numTimerTicks;
  //  [instance configView];
   NSLog(@"the home array is %@",instance.homeImageArray);
   [roundedButtonType setBackgroundImage:[instance.homeImageArray objectAtIndex:numTimerTicks] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [roundedButtonType addTarget:self action:@selector(showDetails:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; //sets the Background image
   [roundedButtonType setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 

  HomePageViewController *homepage = [[HomePageViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"HomePageViewController" bundle:nil];
  [homepage.view addSubview:roundedButtonType];


   //Oops forgot to add this one... my bad.. :D :D
   [self.view addSubview:homepage.view];// Image displayed but goes into endless loop

}
```

Could anyone let me know if I've been doing it right and what I've been missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

instead of this:

```
[homepage.view addSubview:roundedButtonType];
```

do this:

```
[self.view addSubview:roundedButtonType];
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is perfectly fine:

```
HomePageViewController *homepage = [[HomePageViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomePageViewController" bundle:nil];
[homepage.view addSubview:roundedButtonType];
```

You button is added to the `HomePageViewController`.

But the `HomePageViewController` isn't added anywhere, so it won't be visible. You have to show it. E.g. with `pushViewController` / `presentModalViewController` on your current ViewController, or `setRootViewController` on the Window.

Comment: thank you. I tried like this. Please let me know if it was right. `HomePageViewController *homepage = [[HomePageViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomePageViewController" bundle:nil];
   [self presentModalViewController:homepage animated:YES];
   [homepage.view addSubview:roundedButtonType];`

Answer (score 0):

The data you provided is not proper. May be this two are reason for this I have given some tips let me know of this is not u wanted.

First
The change in UI call must happen from main thread. Do one thing. Run the method in the`[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector() withObject:nil waitUntilDone:]`

Second
The homepage.view is not visible. You can give self.view(if u r calling this method from the viewcontroller).